# WP Conctact from 7 hook - add additional mail is chekbox in form is checked (wpc7)

Tags: wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I have Contact Form 7 in my WordPress. The form has two text boxes and one checkbox. How can I send a copy of the letter, if chekbok selected? Perhaps there is a hook, which allows you to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this by editing the form tag, of course in your case you would edit the checkbox form tag and not the select form tag shown below :

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                "Sales|sales@example.com"
                "Support|support@example.com"]
```

and then editing your mail tag like so:

```
[_raw_{field name}] ([_raw_your-recipient]
```

For a more in depth explanation check out this link: https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: Look this http://uploads.ru/J7EI9.png. I want to see if checkbox is checked, the message is duplicated to the specified address.